# Highlight a Cell in Excel Based on Identical Contents in a Column with Varying Contents

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use a formula with conditional formatting or a VBA macro to highlight a cell based on a cell with identical contents in another column, with varying data.

To explain more thoroughly, let's say I have column A, with unique content in each row, rows 1-280.  Each row is formatted to be a string of text, such as "12E00" or "97EBC." I also have column T, which is based on imported data, and may contain some of, but not all of, nor in the same row, the data from column A. It also starts at row 9, not row 1. This is repeated on 47 different tabs, with differing row contents on different tabs (some may have 1-280, others may have 1-160).

Is there some conditional formatting formula/macro (with an explanation of the working components of possible, so that I can learn myself and educate my supervision on the inner workings) that would allow me to highlight any of the cells in column A that have the same text string shown somewhere in column T? Additionally, keeping in mind that I'm checking every row in column A against column T and that column T will only contain some of the text strings in column A.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a better way to accomplish this.

But if I understood the question correctly, then try using: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(cell,column,0))`

I would then make a column next to Column A for each sheet you want to check.

[Example table, with a column for each sheet checked, and a column for checking if any sheets matched. Matched cells are highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrQon.png)

47 columns might be too much to, therefore I used Column B to do:

`=OR(Table1[@[sheetName]:[otherSheetName]])`

Each column have the formula: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH([@[Column A]],INDIRECT(C$1&"!T:T"),0))` (C$1 is pointing to the column's header row)

Utilizing `INDIRECT()` the column will always look in column T in the sheet with the same name as the column header.

The highlighting is done with [these conditional formatting rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ZAw.png)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help and response, but I may not have come across clearly enough (and admittedly, a text entry is confusing without examples) in my question. Now that I have access to Excel and have made an example, hopefully this helps more clearly articulate what I'm attempting to do. https://imgur.com/a/p32pV